# Ruby: Minitest/spec and BDD Gherkin

Tags: ruby, bdd, minitest

It seems that I cannot find much documentation on Minitest/spec so I was wondering if somebody could help me figure out how to do what I need to do.  Basically I want to run tests on all my classes and modules to make sure they 1.) Output the right value type if static or 2.) In the case of to_symbols all keys are symbols.  Here is what I tried so far:

What I assume the Gherkin would look like:

```
Given binns
When the version method is called
then the return should be a float
and version should be a method or constant
```

What I assumed it would be with minitest/spec:

```
require 'minitest/autorun'
require 'minitest/spec'
require 'binns'

given Binns do
  when "the version method is called" do
    then "the return should be a float" do
      # Do work
    end
  end
end
```

But I get:

```
syntax error, unexpected keyword_when (SyntaxError)
  when "the version method is called" do
      ^
```

Note: I am also open to other suggestions for testing (I don't know much about cucumber and heard it was hefty) or if somebody has a book suggestion, please do tell I've been looking  for a good book on Ruby Unit Testing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MiniTest/Spec uses Rspec-style syntax: desc, it, before, after...

```
require 'minitest/autorun'
require 'minitest/spec'
require 'binns'

desc Binns do
  it "should return a float when the version method is called" do
    # Do work
  end
end
```

If it'd make the transition easier for you, you could alias the "desc" method to "given" and "it" method to "when".

[Good tutorial from Peter Cooper here.](http://www.rubyinside.com/a-minitestspec-tutorial-elegant-spec-style-testing-that-comes-with-ruby-5354.html)